# Firms choosing upgrade & minimizing choice

Tags: microeconomics, producer-theory

Imagine hypothetically, there is a firm that has two option for production technology:

f(z) = √z but also the option to increase efficiency to g(z) = 2√z but this choice includes fixed cost F > 0.

What would be the firms cost function if the cost minimizing choice is choosen.

Here's what I've done:

C = wz + F
C = Q^2 /4 + F

But I'm struggling to figure out which choice would be the cost minimizing choice as I could solve the cost function but don't understand which is cost minimizing in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the problem details, it is not a two plant problem. It is a problem with only one plant, with an option of upgrade. Clearly, the firm will exercise the upgrade option only if it is beneficial for it. So the cost function is simply:
$$c(q) = \min\left(wq^2, \frac{wq^2}{4} + F\right)$$
where $w$ is the per unit price of the input $z$.